# Pandas how to filter previous rows based on later row

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe like this

```
Day,Minute,Second,Value
1,1,0,1
1,2,1,2
1,3,1,2
1,2,6,0
1,2,1,1
1,2,5,1
2,0,1,1
2,0,5,2
```

Sometimes the sensor records incorrect values and gets added again but with the correct value. For example, here we should delete the second and third rows since they are being overridden by row four coming from a timestamp before them. How do I filter out the 'bad' rows like those that are unnecessary? For the example, the expected output should be:

```
Day,Minute,Second,Value
1,1,0,1
1,2,1,1
1,2,5,1
2,0,1,1
2,0,5,2
```

Here's the pseudocode for an iterative solution(Sorry for no indents in the formatting this is my first post)

```
for row in dataframe:
for previous_row in rows in dataframe before row:
if previous_row > row:
delete previous row
```

I think there should be a vectorized solution, especially for the second loop. I also don't want to modify what I'm iterating over but I'm not sure there is another option other than duplicating the dataframe.

Here is some starter code to work with the example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'Day':1, 'Minute':1, 'Second':0, 'Value':1},
{'Day':1, 'Minute':2, 'Second':1, 'Value':2}, 
{'Day':1, 'Minute':2, 'Second':6, 'Value':2}, 
{'Day':1, 'Minute':3, 'Second':1, 'Value':0},
{'Day':1, 'Minute':2, 'Second':1, 'Value':1},
{'Day':1, 'Minute':2, 'Second':5, 'Value':1}, 
{'Day':2, 'Minute':0, 'Second':1, 'Value':1}, 
{'Day':2, 'Minute':0, 'Second':5, 'Value':2}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: What constitutes a "bad value"? It is unclear from your question.

Comment: You mean, you want any row with a `1` in `Value`? This is bread-and-butter pandas if so and answered by any tutorial. If not, you need to clarify the rule.

Comment: No, it means a value that is should be overwritten since the sensor will 'start over' re-recording previous rows, overriding the old value. Here, on the first day after the third row the sensor re-calibrates the data, adding the day1 minute2 second1 again and day1 minute2 second6 again. Keep in mind the seconds might also be recalibrated

Comment: If anyone has a better way to phrase this problem I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple rows for the same combination of `Day, Minute, Second` but a different `Value`, I am assuming you want to retain the last recorded value and discard all the previous ones considering they are "bad".

You can do this simply by using `drop_duplicates`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Day', 'Minute', 'Second'], keep='last')
```

**UPDATE v2:**

If you need to retain the last group of `['Minute', 'Second']` combinations for each day, identify monotonically increasing `Minute` groups (since it's the bigger time unit of the two) and select the group with the `max` value of `Group_Id` for each `['Day']`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for _, g in df.groupby(['Day']):
    g['Group_Id'] = (g.Minute.diff() < 0).cumsum()
    res = pd.concat([res, g[g['Group_Id'] == max(g['Group_Id'].values)]])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Day Minute  Second  Value   Group_Id
1   2       1       1       1
1   2       5       1       1
2   0       1       1       0
2   0       5       2       0
```

Comment: This works, but sometimes the timestamp also gets changed, or a measurement should be deleted(Edited the example for clarity). Do you know how I could handle that?

Comment: Do you wish to retain only the rows for a specific day recorded after your sensor restarts?

Comment: I wish all the days would be retained but you could just ignore the day column for now, I think I could use a groupby to eliminate that problem. I just wish that when the sensor recalibrates the data that should be overridden gets filtered out. So at every row, if the rows preceding it are before it, those rows get deleted.

Comment: @CSHhhh Updated the answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Close, the only problem is in the updated example dataframe where day1 minute3 does not get removed

Comment: @CSHhhh Updated again! :)